# Отображение изображений на почте из base64

Tags: php, email, sendmail, base64

Получаю вот такой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу отправить его на почту, чтобы было видно изображения.

```
<?php
    if($_POST != Array()) {
        $arr = $_POST['data'];

        $to = 'example@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Новый объект';
        $message = '<html><head><title>'.$subject.'</title></head><body>';
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            if(preg_match("/^data:image/",$v)) {
                $message .= '<img src="'.$v.'">';
            } else {
                $message .= $v."<br>";
            }
        };
        $message .= "</body></html>";
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Новые объекты <noreply@example.com>\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
```

Но приходит вот так, в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почтовые клиенты блокируют отображение изображений из base64. Можно только вложениями отправлять или вставлять ссылки на ранее загруженные изображения на сервере.