# Как отправить изображение base64 через WordPress contact form 7?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Возникла проблема. У меня есть канвас и картинка, которая в нем генерируется. При отправке формы я конвертирую изображение в base64:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Оно возвращает нужное значение и я вывожу картинку на странице. К этому моменту все работает. Дальше начинаются проблемы:

1- В форме есть скрытый инпут, в котором храниться данная строка (data). Отправляю.

2- 
`<img src="[text-918]" class=""/>` это из письма, интерфейса contact form 7. Вместо [text-918] помещается base64 ссылка. Такие теги как h1, p отображает и галочка, разрешающая html тоже включена

Но когда приходит на почту - вместо картинки получаю `<img src="....` и вся ссылка в текстовом варианте. При чем не вся, ее образает, ставит ... в через =2000 символов.

Уже много чего пробовал - не могу найти как исправить. Усложняет все использование вордпресса и плагина contact form

Comment: А что вам мешает загрузить файл на сервер и/или отправить его? https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: @Walfter Это поле для вставки файла. Его можно заполнить только с компьютера, а не с помощью js. Или... я не прав?

Comment: Да, извиняюсь не совсем уловил суть вопроса, тогда попробуйте `canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");`

Comment: @Walfter такой же результат..

Comment: Если я правильно уловил суть проблемы с этой страницы https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-an-image-to-contact-form-7/ то CF7 проверяет поле на существование картинки по ссылке, и если его нет отправляет как текст

Comment: @Walfter она не может не существовать, т.к этот url и есть картинка. Или он проверяет только по ссылке в интернете.

Comment: Всё же думаю он проверяет её на доступность url'а, так как это base64... Думаю он считает это фальшивой ссылкой и экранирует её...

Comment: @Walfter нашел информацию. Все ссылки почта читает как текст, и если суммарный текст больше 102 кб - обрезает. Ну а обрезанный текст уже точно не отображает как тег

Comment: Вот до чего я дошёл https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655023/Отображение-изображений-на-почте-из-base64

Comment: Вы не отправите base64 на почту, сохраните его до отправки, получите url и отправьте его

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93737/discussion-between-walfter-and-shumik-ua).